# Communicate with oAuth enabled API from Laravel 5

Tags: php, api, laravel, oauth

I am developing a website in laravel 5.1. I need to write code which will communicate with some other system using API call. Other system is projected by oAuth. So I first need to authenticate my system using oAuth and then i can make the api.

I am not sure how i can achieve this in laravel. Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [laravel/socialite](https://github.com/laravel/socialite) and its documentation [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#social-authentication).

This library currently supports Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, Google, GitHub and Bitbucket, but it will be pretty easy to create your own custom provider. Just take a look at source code on github.

Other than this you could use some standalone OAuth library like [league/oauth2-client](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client). There is also library dedicated for first version of OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can achieve your goal.

**Laravel Specific Method**
There are many packages for handling oAuth Authentication.. e.g. [OAuth Service Provider for Laravel 5](https://github.com/oriceon/oauth-5-laravel) from github. You can search similar other packages and use them.

**Guzzle**
As you need to call the api anyway after the authentication, you need CURL or other packages to do the call. Here [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org) can help you. Also you can use Guzzle to code your full oAuth Authentication.

**Plain PHP Method**
You can use [OAuth](http://php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php) class library to code the oAuth Authentication OR use [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Personally I've used Guzzle only to get the Code, Access Token, Refresh Token etc. I hope you'll manage to use Guzzle for this purpose.